# REST API for SOLR analyzer

Tags: solr

I'm going to test my SOLR analyzer and I've found instructions how to do it here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Your+Analyzer.

But I need to check several thousand of words, so I'm going to do it programmatically, not manually. Does SOLR have any REST API to run analyzer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solr Admin page is just a set of static HTML files that uses [the REST API offered by Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/implicit-requesthandlers.html#analysis-handlers) behind the scenes. If you watch the `Network` tab in your browser's developer tools while navigating it, you'll see all the endpoints it talks to.

After doing this on the Analysis page, you can see that it makes requests to three endpoints, one to fetch the HTML, then two new requests to get the schema (for the field list) and one to perform the actual analysis:

> http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue=asd&analysis.query=asd&analysis.fieldname=content